# enable dom file inside the php.ini

Tags: laravel

I'm facing  some problems with the laravel  in every time I create the new one or update the composer  I get this error "phpunit/phpunit 7.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system". .I'm pretty sure that I've installed the dom file but the problem cant find it inside the php.ini althought I tried to do that by type "extension=dom.so "

Comment: Which OS are you on ?

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention about the Os it is Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in your ubuntu server.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml